# Talking to remote CouchDB server from Android

Tags: java, android, couchdb

I'm designing a turn based game similar to *Words With Friends*. I don't need the data to be stored persistently on the phone in a local CouchDB.

I've attempted HTTP requests using [`HttpPut`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPut.html)/[`HttpGet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) and [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) with no success.

What is the best way to communicate with CouchDB from an Android application? What alternative database backends are available?

Comment: You should elaborate why you didn't succeed because that is the way to talk to CouchDB, using basic HTTP requests.

Comment: In the current form your question is going to be closed as *not a real question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [TouchDB-Android](http://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android).  We've been using [TouchDB-iOS](http://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS) for our iOS apps and are planning on using TouchDB-Android when we start Android development.  TouchDB has an active development community -- see this [google group](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase).  You can use TouchDB to connect to a local or remote CouchdB database and to replicate between the two.